# Replacement of 'pos() const' which is marked as deprecated

Tags: python, pyside, pyside6

I'm learning Pyside6 and I have following method:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
        self.offset = event.pos()
    else:
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
```

When I run my script, I get following warning:

> *DeprecationWarning: Function: 'pos() const' is marked as deprecated*

Which method should I use to replace pos() ?

Comment: use `event.position()`